# Pycharm: disable automatic unfolding of collapsed blocks

Tags: pycharm

It is often useful to define code fold `# region`s in pycharm.

However, when **scrolling with the cursor at the end of a line** (not at the origin) through the code with the regions collapsed, pycharm **automatically unfolds** the regions, creating a disturbing and dynamic reading surface, with text popping and moving around rapidly.

The general value of code folding is to reduce this distracting behavior. So this default setting invades the specific value code folding can provide.

---

How does one disable this cursor-driven, automatic unfolding behavior when **scrolling** with the cursor in pycharm?

This issue appears specifically when the cursor begins at end of a line (the newline delimiter) and is moved up or down from there; it does not occur when the cursor is placed at the origin of the line.

It also does not impact folded code; it only impacts folded multi-line strings (comments) and `# region/# endregion` areas.

---

Finally, **although** this behavior does not occur when the cursor is at the origin, the **cursor cannot be *returned to the origin* on any empty line**. It must be returned to the origin on a line with content.

Thus, once the cursor is at the end of the register, I must stop what I am doing, find a line of content that is code, and return the cursor to the origin from there.

When all of the code is collapsed, the majority of the lines are blank, and any code lines are usually a few hops away -- hops that may trigger a region to pop open!

Thus three keystrokes (J-J-0) may turn into 6 (J-(f*k)-Z-C-J-0).  I've parenthesized my thoughts and counted them as a keystroke.

This is definitely more deployed brain power than I want for a level of control that should be like dealing cards (automatic) rather than decisioning.

How does one fix this?

Comment: I just looked into this and tried to reproduce it. Perhaps you are using an older version of PyCharm, I vaguely seem to recall this unfolding behavior from older versions, but I wasn't able to reproduce it in the PyCharm 2021.2.2 version, the [current documentation on folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding) also gives no indication about the behavior beyond that you might be refactoring something that *"If PyCharm changes code in the folded fragment during the code reformatting, the code fragment will be automatically expanded."*.

Comment: @bad_coder yeah, over the years I have found this to be behavior that leaves and returns in pycharm/clion etc.  I suppose the code that runs this component could be one of those highly optimized squirrel nest situations that keeps getting broken (organized) and repaired (reluctantly re-implemented).